# DevOps pipeline replace() function not working as expected

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to use the replace function in a DevOps pipeline as documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#replace

For the following yml, I expect the output to be **This should be steak but it is steak**, however the actual output is **This should be steak but it is beef**

```yml
variables:
  foo: 'beef'
  bar: $[replace('$(foo)', 'beef', 'steak')]

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- script: echo This should be steak but it is $(bar)
```

I have also tried this will the same output

```yml
variables:
  foo: 'beef'

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- script: echo This should be steak but it is ${{ replace('$(foo)', 'beef', 'steak') }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `variables['foo']` to replace the `$(foo)`.

Here is my example:

```
variables:
  foo: 'beef'
  bar: $[replace(variables['foo'], 'beef', 'steak')]

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- script: echo This should be steak but it is $(bar)
```

The Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much 

Comment: Then how do you do that in variables for `System.PullRequest.SourceBranch` ?